# Consulta con esta relación multitabla en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

en estos momento me encuentro realizando una consulta en SQL SERVER donde debo mostrar el listado de unos Toures pero estos tienne unos idiomas los cuales pueden ser diferentes para varios es decir un tour puede manejar un solo idioma, dos idiomas, o tres idiomas dependiendo el registro que se realice y los idiomas que se les agregue a cada Tour.

```
SELECT 
TID.Ididioma_Tour,
TID.Ididioma,
Sistema.Idiomas.Nombre AS 'Idioma',
TDB.Nombre as 'Tour'
FROM
Tour.DatosBasicos AS TDB
LEFT JOIN Tour.Idiomas AS TID ON TID.Idtour = TDB.Idtour
LEFT JOIN Sistema.Idiomas ON TID.Ididioma = Sistema.Idiomas.Ididioma
```

Con esta consulta se me muestran repetidos los Toures ya registrados previamente los cuales en si son 9 Toures en total y se me muestran 10 y si agrego otro Idioma al Tour se me muestran 11 y asi sucesivamente y si realizo un select solo para mi tabla que contine los Toues que seria en este caso Tour.DatosBasicos me doy cuenta que estan registrados solo los 9 iniciales y no encuentro la forma que en la consulta me muestre solo los 9 iniciales o no se si estoy herrado en la forma de la consulta

Comment: pero no estoy entendiendo....si estás haciendo un `select` para obtener el idioma del tour, y algunos tours tienen más de un idioma, cómo esperas que no te muestre más de una fila para ese tour?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: En si necesito que no me muestre los Toures duplicados por ejemplo el Tour Viaje por el caribe si este tiene dos idiomas solo se me muestre 1 solo registro ya en otra vista se muestran los multiplex idiomas del mismo

Comment: pero en el select estás pidiendo el idioma, entonces cuál idioma quieres que muestre?

Comment: Seria el idioma predeterminado o por defecto que seria Español

Comment: y cómo se sabe cuál idioma es el predeterminado?. Por favor, trata de poner los detalles de lo que estás solicitando en la pregunta

Comment: Mil disculpas, soy nuevo en esto. el idioma por defecto seria Español y en el select seria esta columna TID.Ididioma aqui estaria el ID del idioma y solo me muestre solo los Toures con el idioma predeterminado y si tiene mas de dos toures no se repitan solo me muestre los Toures con el idioma en español

Comment: pero es que entonces para qué necesitas hacer join con la tabla de idiomas?....cada tour tiene predeterminado el español, y si tiene más de un idioma no quieres que se muestre....no sería suficiente con hacer un select al tour y poner idioma español no más?

Comment: Que versión (Año) de SQL Server estás usando?, lo ves haciendo "SELECT @@Version"

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5029377) - 15.0.2104.1 (X64)   Aug 16 2023 00:09:21   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: )